# .NetCore Prometheus MetricServer how to change port

Tags: .net-core, prometheus

we can acces prometheus metrics by localhost:22990/metrics but we want to change it to

`localhost:22300/metrics`. In `Startup.cs` I have changed to this

```
   app.Map("/metrics", metricsApp =>
    {
        metricsApp.UseMiddleware<BasicAuthMW>("Corporation");
        metricsApp.UseMetricServer(22300);
   
    });       
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseHttpMetrics();
```

but Chrome says `http://localhost:22300/metrics`
This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

also `localhost:22990/metrics`  is still active, how can I change it. thank you

Comment: I really need this

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to prometheus-net version 8.0.0 and use this extension method.

```
builder.Services.AddMetricServer(options =>
{
    options.Port = 1234;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work using `services.AddMetricServer(options => options.Port = 22300);`

Of **IServiceCollection** services in ConfigureServices method.
To stop metrics on default application port , need to remove `endpoints.MapMetrics();`
from `app.UseEndpoints`